# Как связать две таблицы по нескольким полям сразу Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Напишу в примерном виде, что хочу получить:

1)Есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM `check` WHERE `uid`='$id'
```

2)Запрос, который хочу получить, где $variant, $subject берутся из первого запроса.

```
SELECT * FROM `appeal` WHERE `variant`='$var' AND `uid`='$id' AND `subject`='$subject
```

Получается связать таблицы только по id:

Контроллер:

```
Variant::with('appealUid')->where('uid',$uid)->get();
```

Модель

```
public function appealUid(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Appeal','uid','uid');
}
```

Не понимаю, как добавить связи и по другим полям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут только использовать Query Builder

```
\DB::table('check')->select([...])->join('appeal',function ($join) {
            $join->on('check.uid', '=', 'appeal.uid');
            $join->on('check.variant', '=', 'appeal.variant');
            $join->on('check.subject', '=', 'appeal.subject');    
        })->where('check.uid',$uid)->get()
```

Comment: Вернуло только записи check. Не связало с appeal

Comment: @Кирилл Желнов Так чет не понял распиши все таблицы которые должны участвовать, чет ты не очень описал задачу

Comment: Check - uid | variant | subject | ball1| ball2| status       Appeal - uid| variant | subject | text_admin | text_user| Надо связать эти две таблицы по uid, variant и subject. Записей с одинаковым uid может быть несколько

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если для записи в таблице check не найдется записи в таблице appeal, то он не выведет запись из check. Можно ли как-то это избежать ?

Comment: @Кирилл Желнов Ну делай тогда leftJoin

Comment: Да, так  сделал. Спасибо